# Which is the best kind of filter papers to use to extract silicon nanoparticles after acid wash, hydeophobic or hydrophilic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, filtering

I'm looking for filter papers to extract silicon nanoparticles after acid etching. I found that much of my material is get wasted with my Whatman Grade 4 filter paper. I am thinking to use membrane filter papers to get the maximum amount of nanoparticles.  However, there are hydrophobic and hydrophilic varieties in the market. I'm confused. Also, is it possible to peel off the nanoparticle layer from the membrane surface?

Thank you

Comment: I never dealt with nanoparticles, but I'd expect extracting them out of solution would make them stick together.